# access aspx hiddenfield by name from request object on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a hiddenfield on front end with master page. I am accessing value of it in code behind from request object as follows by hardcoding value of element name(read from f12 dev tools on rendered ui).

```
Request['ctl00$MainContent$fieldname']
```

Right now since Ui uses master page `fieldname` changes to `ctl00$MainContent$fieldname`. I am unable to use `eleName.value` in code behind because value of it is being used in inner functions which are called from multiple locations. To avoid impact on other components i am fetching it directly in inner function from req obj.

I am not sure if hardcoding the value will work if there are many users accessing the UI. Is it safe to assume `ctl00$MainContent$fieldname` will always be same for different users if they access the resource?

Or is there better way to fetch name of element/to generate one string with `clientid$fieldname` format to be used to fetch value out request?

Comment: The id you show is the client side id, and it depends on the position in control tree - you should access the controls via its server side ID or FindControl. You can make html controls server side.

Comment: Thank you for you input. I used page findcontrol uniquename to get dynamic name of the field. Works perfect :)